# How to find out middle string that begin [local] and end with # in python

Tags: python

```
import re
line = '[local]SEPCF004#'
middle_str = re.search('[local](.+?)#', line).group(1)
```

When I use above regular expression code then [local] does not treat a string.
My requirement is that i want to find out those string which start by `[local]` and ends with `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this

```
(?<=\[local\]).*?(?=#)
```

with re.findall.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/1TxF6I/1

```
x='[local]SEPCF004#'
print re.findall(r"(?<=\[local\]).*?(?=#)", x)
```

output:

```
['SEPCF004']
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting this?

```
import re 
line = '[local]SEPCF004#' 
middle_str = re.search('\[local\](.*)#', line).group(1)
middle_str

Output :
'SEPCF004'
```

Comment: I think he wants group(0)

Answer (score 0):

Code below should do, it try to match anything(including space or empty) between [local] and #

```
middle_str = re.search('\[local\](.*)#', line).group(1)
```